# Xpath error with not() and ends-with()

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following Xpath expression:

```
//*[not(input)][ends-with(@*, 'Copyright')]
```

I expect it to give me all elements - except input - with any attribute value which ends with "Copyright".

I execute it in the Selenium 2 Java API with `webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(expression))` and get the following error:

> The expression is not a legal
>   expression

But these expressions work without trouble:

```
//*[not(input)][starts-with(@*, 'Copyright')]
//*[ends-with(@*, 'Copyright')]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know Selenium but if `//*[not(input)][starts-with(@*, 'Copyright')]` is parsed successfully and if additionally the XPath 2.0 function `ends-with` is supported then I don't see any reason why `//*[not(input)][ends-with(@*, 'Copyright')]` is not accepted as a legal expression. Your verbal description however sounds as if you want `//*[not(self::input)][@*[ends-with(., 'Copyright')]]`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What's the difference between `//*[not(self::input)][@*[ends-with(., 'Copyright')]]` and `//*[not(input)][ends-with(@*, 'Copyright')]`?

Comment: `//*[not(input)]` selects any elements not having any `input` child element while `//*[not(self::input)]` selects any elements not being themselves `input` elements. As for comparing `[@*[ends-with(., 'Copyright')]]` with what you have, my suggestion is true as long as there is any attribute node which ends with 'Copyright' while your test would only work if there is a single attribute which ends with 'Copyright', as ends-with (http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-ends-with) allow a sequence with a single item as its first argument or an empty sequence but not several items.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try this out. You could create an answer so that i can mark it as the solution if it works.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for analysis and explanation of the problems with your XPath expression. Following this, a complete XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0 solutions are presented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have the following Xpath expression:
>
> ```
> //*[not(input)][ends-with(@*, 'Copyright')]
> ```
>
> I expect it to give me all elements -
>   except input - with any attribute
>   value which ends with "Copyright".

**There are a few issues here**:

1. `ends-with()` is a standard XPath 2.0 function only, so the chances are you are using an XPath 1.0 engine and it correctly raises an error because it doesn't know about a function called `ends-with()`.
2. Even if you are working with an XPath 2.0 processor, the expression `ends-with(@*, 'Copyright')` results in error in the general case, because the `ends-with()` function is defined to accept atmost a single string (`xs:string?`) as both of its operands -- however `@*` produces a sequence of more than one string in the case when the element has more than one attribute.
3. `//*[not(input)]` doesn't mean "select all elements that are not named `input`. The real meaning is: "Select all elements that dont have a child element named "input".

**Solution**:

1. Use this XPath 2.0 expression: `//*[not(self::input)][@*[ends-with(.,'Copyright')]]`
2. In the case of XPath 1.0 use this expression:

....

```
  //*[not(self::input)]
        [@*[substring(., string-length() -8) = 'Copyright']]
```

**Here is a short and complete verification of the last XPath expression, using XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "//*[not(self::input)]
           [@*[substring(., string-length() -8)
              = 'Copyright'
              ]
          ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<html>
 <input/>
 <a x="Copyright not"/>
 <a y="This is a Copyright"/>
</html>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a y="This is a Copyright"/>
```

**In the case of the XML document being in a default namespace**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "//*[not(self::x:input)]
           [@*[substring(., string-length() -8)
              = 'Copyright'
              ]
          ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <input z="This is a Copyright"/>
 <a x="Copyright not"/>
 <a y="This is a Copyright"/>
</html>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" y="This is a Copyright"/>
```

Comment: Sadly not working too: The expression is not a legal expression: xpath=//*[not(self::input)][@*[substring(., string-length()-8) = 'Copyright')]]

Comment: @Alp: Seems you are not working with a compliant XPath processor -- if so, your question will be better adressed in a more specific tag, not in the "xpath" tag, which assumes that the question is an XPath question.

Comment: @Alp: I edited my answer and it now includes a complete XSLT-based verification of the second XPath expression. You may just run this verification yourself and see that the wanted result is produced.

Comment: Selenium uses the browser's XPath engine so it is likely a complete implementation. I've had issues with frames or multiple windows and Selenium focus for XPaths. Are you using any of those features?

Comment: Please, note, @Adam, that "complete" isn't a synonym for "compliant" or "correct". There is a W3C test suite -- run Selenium on it.

Comment: @Dimitre - I believe we've had this discussion in other comment threads. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Selenium but if `//*[not(input)][starts-with(@*, 'Copyright')]` is parsed successfully and if additionally the XPath 2.0 function `ends-with` is supported then I don't see any reason why `//*[not(input)][ends-with(@*, 'Copyright')]` is not accepted as a legal expression. Your verbal description however sounds as if you want `//*[not(self::input)][@*[ends-with(., 'Copyright')]]`.

`//*[not(input)]` selects any elements not having any input child element while `//*[not(self::input)]` selects any elements not being themselves `input` elements. As for comparing `[@*[ends-with(., 'Copyright')]]` with what you have, my suggestion is true as long as there is any attribute node which ends with 'Copyright' while your test would only work if there is a single attribute which ends with 'Copyright', as ends-with http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-ends-with allow a sequence with a single item as its first argument or an empty sequence but not several items.

Comment: Got the same error for `//*[not(self::input)][@*[ends-with(., 'Copyright')]]`.

Comment: Are you sure Selenium supports an XPath 2.0 function like `ends-with`?

Comment: As far as I understand XPath the expressions are fine. However I don't know Selenium so I don't know why it complains and can't help with that. Hopefully someone else comes along and can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your help. I think i have to ask this in the Selenium usergroup.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: [Re: I don't see any reason why `//*[not(input)][ends-with(@*, 'Copyright')]` is not accepted as a legal expression] See my answer for explanation why this should produce (as it does) a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely explanation is that you are using an XPath 1.0 processors. The ends-with() function requires XPath 2.0 support.

Comment: Yes, `starts-with` is also from XPath 2.0

Comment: No, starts-with was available in 1.0. ends-with was new in 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[not(self::input)][@*[substring(., string-length(.) -8) = 'Copyright']]
```

May be small correction with `string-length(.)`

Now, it may work.