# Need help Identifying fields with dynamic names using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I would like to type in the date as following: 2015/05/05 in to that field. the idea is to use the ends-with command. So far the following didn't work

```
//input[ends-with(@id,'_ExecutionDate')and contains(.,'ExecutionDate')][@class='emphasis']

//div[ends-with(@id,'_ExecutionDate')and contains(.,'ExecutionDate')][@class='emphasis']
```

Here is a XPATH from Selenium's Select option: 
xpath=(//input[@id='44d02654-39b3-447e-904d-8d3c7ca016b6.ExecutionDate'])[3]

Her is an xpath from Firebug:

```
.//*[@id='44d02654-39b3-447e-904d-8d3c7ca016b6.ExecutionDate']
```

Here is a code:

```
<div class="pull-right" data-bind="visible: view.isIndividual"><!-- ko foreach: signingParties -->
<a id="44d02654-39b3-447e-904d-8d3c7ca016b6.ExecutionDate" class="emphasis" style="margin-right:5px" data-bind="visible: !$root.locked(), click: $root.transferOfLand.view.editExecutionDates, valName: 'ExecutionDate', text: view.executionDateDisplay()" href="#" name="44d02654-39b3-447e-904d-8d3c7ca016b6.ExecutionDate" data-val="LandTransferDocument.Transferor.0.SigningParty.ExecutionDate">Add Execution Date...</a>
<span id="44d02654-39b3-447e-904d-8d3c7ca016b6.ExecutionDate" style="margin-right: 5px; display: none;" data-bind="visible: $root.locked(), valName: 'ExecutionDate', text: view.executionDateDisplayReadOnly()" name="44d02654-39b3-447e-904d-8d3c7ca016b6.ExecutionDate" data-val="LandTransferDocument.Transferor.0.SigningParty.ExecutionDate">No Execution Date</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ends-with()` is a part of `XPath 2.0` and, hence, cannot be used here, see details at:

- [Xpath error with not() and ends-with()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167443/xpath-error-with-not-and-ends-with)

Instead, use `contains()`:

```
//input[contains(@id,'ExecutionDate')]
```

---

Alternatively, there is an ends-with *CSS selector*:

```
input[id$=ExecutionDate]
```

Comment: Hey, alecxe. so far no luck. it is not working. I tried both of these solutions.

Comment: @OlegMikhalitsyn could be a different problem. Are there any iframes on the page?

Comment: @alexce Yes, this field is within the pop-up window. So the class of the pop-up window is class="k-widget k-window". should I add it or the class of the field is enough because the input has it's own class?

Comment: It worked when I included @date val="value" as well //input[contains(@id,'_ExecutionDate')][@data-val='value']

Comment: @OlegMikhalitsyn looks like you've solved it. Consider accepting the answer to close the topic. Thanks.

Comment: why are you using underscore when the id is .ExecututionDate?