# using substring in xpath selenium with Java

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have `id`'s (all `div`s I am afraid) like this:

```
<div id ='p1:pdr0'>
<div id = 'p1:pdr0:content'>
<div id = 'p1:pdr0:blahblahblah'>
...
```

I want just to find the first one.  I could use the entire id, but the first part could change.  I want to do `ends-with(@id,'pdr0')` but there is no `ends-with()`.

Someone did suggest using a `substring(length-3)`. I did look up in google. It showed a function but not a specific example of how to use it in an xpath. Would it just be `//div[fn:(substring(fn:length(@id)-3))]`?  Probably not.

Can someone show me an example of using substring and length of an id in an xpath expression? (By the way the exact id names are not exactly that.  Suffice to say they all contain the same text but some have more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ends-with()` is a part of XPath 2.0 and hence [cannot be used in your case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167443/xpath-error-with-not-and-ends-with).

There is `contains()`, but, if we are talking about pure XPath approach, it would not help since `pdr0` is also present in `id` attributes of other `div` elements.

Note that, if the order of the `div` elements is the one you've provided, you can rely on the position of the element (indexing starts from 1):

```
//div[contains(@id, 'pdr0')][1]
```

---

The more reliable option would be to simulate `ends-with()` using [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring) with [`string-length()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/string-length):

```
//div[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 3) = 'pdr0']
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted.  Thanks

Comment: Looking for the accept button.  I know I did it before but I don't see it.  A few minutes later -- found it ;-)